# How to apply formatting to v-model value and remove formatting before commiting in store

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I'm assigning a vueex store value to a v-model in a v-text-field.
This value is stored as an integer. Is there a way to simply format this value and let the user change it and remove formatting when he applies changes?

The format is ##:##:## 
But the value is stored in seconds.

I am using this approach: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Here's how my store is built. I keep it simple:

```
...
 mutations: {
...
    updateSwimFtp (state, swimFtp) {
      state.athlete.swimFtp = swimFtp
    }
...
  },
...
```

In my vue component, I use a computed attribute to get the value and store use it in the v-model. The formatting happens in the get() and the unformatring happens in the set().

```
...
        <v-text-field
                :label="$vuetify.t('$vuetify.swimFtp')"
                :hint="$vuetify.t('$vuetify.swimFtp')"
                mask="time-with-seconds"
                v-model="swimFtp"
                required>
        </v-text-field>



...
        computed: {
            athlete() {
                return this.$store.state.athlete
            },

            swimFtp: {
                get () {
                    var date = new Date(null);
                    date.setSeconds(this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp);
                    return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
                },
                set (value) {
                var hoursInSecs = parseInt (String( this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp ).substring(0, 2),10)*60*60;
                var minsInSecs = parseInt (String( this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp ).substring(3, 5),10)*60;
                var secs = parseInt (String( this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp ).substring(6, 8),10);
                var _secsToStore = hoursInSecs+minsInSecs+secs;
                    this.$store.commit('updateSwimFtp', _secsToStore);
                }
            },

        },
...
```

The problem with this approach is that when the user clicks on back/delete key it calls the set() method. Since it's two way binding approach, the value gets stored with wrong value and the get() is formating it again.

Is there a way to only use the return key event from the text field or is there an other aproach I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got something working.

Simplified the store.js methods:

```
  mutations: {
    setSwimFtp (state, swimFtp) {
      state.athlete.swimFtp = swimFtp
    }
  },

  actions: {
    //TODO post to server here
    updateSwimFtp ({ commit }, value) {
      commit('setSwimFtp', value);
    }
  }
```

In my vue component, I have added to the text field an instruction to return the masked value. This will return the value with the mask.

```
<template>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
    <form
            lazy-validation
            ref="form">
        <v-text-field
                :label="$vuetify.t('$vuetify.swimFtp')"
                :hint="$vuetify.t('$vuetify.swimFtp')"
                v-model="swimFtp"
                mask="time-with-seconds"
                return-masked-value="true"
                required>
        </v-text-field>

        <v-btn @click="**submit**">submit</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="clear">clear</v-btn>
    </form>

    </v-flex>
</template>
```

I have simplified the setter to store the masked value without trying to unformat the value. This fixes the flickering of the field when the user if modifying the value. Vue.js will react to every change and the get will show partial user input. So just store what's in the field.

```
        computed: {

            swimFtp: {
                get () {
                    var date = new Date(null);
                    var _val = String(this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp);
                    if ( _val.includes(":") )
                        return this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp;
                    else {
                        date.setSeconds(this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp);
                        return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
                    }
                },


                set (value) {
                    this.$store.commit('setSwimFtp', value);
                }
            }

        },
```

And finally, at submit of the form, I remove the formatting to make sure the value is sent to the server database in seconds, not with a masked value.

```
        methods: {

            submit: function() {
                var hoursInSecs = parseInt (String( this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp ).substring(0, 2),10)*60*60;
                var minsInSecs = parseInt (String( this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp ).substring(3, 5),10)*60;
                var secs = parseInt (String( this.$store.state.athlete.swimFtp ).substring(6, 8),10);
                var _secsToStore = hoursInSecs+minsInSecs+secs;
                this.$store.dispatch('updateSwimFtp', _secsToStore)
            },

        },
```